# Nodejs: sorting paragraph numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I am trying to sort some paragraph numbers which have been extracted from a document.

Unfortunately they are not true decimals so the standard `sort` functions don't work. For example I want the following result: `["3.1","3.2","3.11"]` NOT `["3.1","3.11","3.2"]` (which is what I get from from using: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

The numbers also have an indeterminate number of decimals. For example they can appear as follows: `["1.i.a","1.i.b","1.i.c.A","1.i.c.B"]`

After working on this problem for a while, I believe the best solution is to treat each number as sub-strings separated by '.'s and compare / order them according to the 'lowest' substring.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done in JS?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You will never need to compare a number to a letter, correct? For example, `3.4` and `3.a` will never need to be compared?

Comment: Some thought: Either your substrings are number, in which case the sort is simple, or they are letter. In that case, you could try to do a lookup table to transform them in number. The only problem will be roman number (`I`, `IV`...) unless you find a way to differentiate them from simple letters reliably.

Comment: @apsillers - yes that is right. all the substrings will be the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that work for you? I can give more explanation if needed.

```
"use strict"
let index = ['3.1.a', '3.2', '3.11', '3.1.c', '3.2.z'];

index.sort((a, b) => {
  var aArr = a.split('.'), bArr = b.split('.')

  for (var i = 0, aLength = aArr.length; i < aLength; i++) {
    let aVal = aArr[i], bVal = bArr[i]
    if (!isNaN(aVal)) aVal = Number(aVal) // convert substring into Number if it is a Number
    if (!isNaN(bVal)) bVal = Number(bVal)

    if (bVal === undefined) return 1 // b lower index
    if (aVal === bVal) continue

    return typeof(aVal) === "string" ? aVal.charCodeAt() - bVal.charCodeAt() : aVal - bVal; // for strings, works only if length == 1
  }

  return bArr[i] === undefined ? 0 : -1 // if b undefined, then both numbers are equal, otherwise a is shorter
})

console.log(index)
// outputs [ '3.1.a', '3.1.c', '3.2', '3.2.z', '3.11' ]
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand this code? I have been using it for a few weeks and am discovering it isn't working 100% for roman numerals (e.g. '3.1.a.vi',3.1.a.iv'). Also when I console log the output, aVal - bVal is returning 'NaN' for alphabets

Comment: You're right, the code here is not working for letters. I can add a little fix for this. For the roman numerals, it's an edgy case, because there is no way to differentiate it from plain letters. Here's what I propose: if a substring corresponds to a roman numeral, it will be considered a roman numeral (e.g. if you have 3.4.i, it will be converted to 3.4.1). What do you think?

Comment: @qts I've fixed the answer so it works correctly with letters. Right now, it will only work if the substring is only a letter. Is that ok?

Comment: Thanks! It's good enough for now if it works for letters. for roman numerals I can do a workaround for now but eventually it would be great to have a solution if one exists, although I think that probably deserves its own separate question.

Comment: Right after you cast to Numbers, you would do an else and try to converr it to a ruman numeral if it fails, then you know it's just plain letters

Comment: I've been testing this and it seems to work. But what is the point of `if (!isNaN(aVal))` and`if (!isNaN(bVal))`? They don't seem necessary to me.

Comment: Hey, sorry forgot about your question. I use it to differentiate Numbers from Strings. `return typeof(aVal) === "string" ? aVal.charCodeAt() - bVal.charCodeAt() : aVal - bVal;` <-- depends on the type. Doing a character minus a character returns `NaN`, so we need to take their ASCII value.

Answer (score 0):

A incomplete and quite rigid way to do it could be this:

```
'use strict';

const async = require('async');

let index = ['3.1.a', '3.2', '3.11', '3.1.c', '3.2.z'];

//'3.1.a' => ['3', '1', 'a']
function paragraphToSubstring(string, callback) {
    async.map(string, (s, callback) => {
        callback(null, s.split('.'));
    }, (err, substrings) => {
        callback(substrings);
    });
}

//['3', '1', 'a'] => [3, 1, 1]
function substringToNumber(substrings) {
    async.map(substrings, (e, callback) {
        let i = parseInt(e);
        //If e is a letter
        if(isNaN(i)) {
            //Take it's ASCII value
            //If you need to support roman number, you'll have to make the check and transformation here
            callback(null, e.charCodeAt(0));
        } else {
            callback(null, i);
        }
    })
}

function sort(paragraphs, callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        //Convert everything in array
        (callback) => {
            async.map(paragraphs, (p, callback) => {
                paragraphToSubstring(p, (s) => {
                    callback(null, s);
                });
            }, (err, substrings) => {
                callback(err, substrings)
            });
        },
        //Convert everything in numbers
        (substrings, callback) => {
            async.map(substrings, (s, callback) => {
                substringToNumber(s, (err, i) => {
                    callback(err, i);
                });
            }, (err, numbers) => {
                callback(err, numbers);
            });
        }
        //Sort
        (numbers, callback) => {
            callback(null, numbers.sort((a, b) => {
                //Didn't found a way to support a undefinite number of element, settled on 3
                let s1 = a[0] - b[0],
                    s2 = a[1] - b[1],
                    s3 = a[2] - b[2];

                if(s1) {
                    return s1;
                }
                if(s2) {
                    return s2;
                }
                if(s3) {
                    return s3;
                }
            }));
        }
    ], (err, sorted) {
        callback(err, sorted);
    });
}
```

Interesting exercise to do, I ll come back later with improvement, when I ll have the time to work more on it.

Comment: I think this is quite an overkill haha

Comment: @jonathanGB: Probably, I did it whithout thinking of performance, and more about readability and handling every error possible.

Comment: why async? there's no I/O or ajax here?

Comment: @jonathanGB: Good point, just more used to async's API than standart object API.